# Retrieve Date from Date/Time Field in SharePoint List with Javascript?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, javascript, jsom, date-time

I am trying to pick up the date for each item in a list but I cannot seem to figure out all to get the value.

I am using:

```
var startDate = listEnumerator.get_current().get_item('Start_x0020_Date')
```

Comment: Can you please add complete code to your question? Are you able to get other fields like Single line text/item ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your success function, you can try something like below:

```
function Success() {
    var listEnumerator = collList.getEnumerator();

    while (listEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var oList = listEnumerator.get_current();
        var startDate = oList.get_item('DateTimeColumnName');  // 'DateTimeColumnName' is internal name of date field
    }
}
```

You can find the complete code to get the list items using JSOM in below article:

[How to: Retrieve Lists Using JavaScript](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/hh185009(v%3Doffice.14)).

**How to find internal name of field**:

1. [How to get Internal names of columns in sharepoint lists?](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)

Comment: I have three different date fields on my list though, how would I differentiate between the three?

Comment: You must be having different internal names for each date and time field. So you can use that. check updated answer to find internal name

Comment: Is it not working? Try first saving current item in one variable and then fetching StartDate from that item as given in answer instead of writing in one line.

Comment: If it is working then please upvote(^) and accept as an answer so that it will help others to find the correct answer easily.